# JQuery Auto Completion with REST API

Tags: jquery, html, rest, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

Please have a look at the below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote JSONP datasource</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
  }
  #city { width: 25em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="city">Your city: </label>
  <input id="city">
  Powered by <a href="http://geonames.org">geonames.org</a>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The code is used for auto completing JQuery text field. You can find the plugin here - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

However, I have a `REST` link where I would like to retrieve the information. I tried replacing the link in the above example, but it didn't work. A sample REST link can be found here - http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/ (I not using this anyway).

So, how can I use this same JQuery auto completion with REST API?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried and what exactly does not work?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe: This question is 1 year old

Comment: Yes, but still no answer I see